# Wrong value on first element in std::vector

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ i am fearly new, i found a bug in my code and could reproduce with a example, in this code i am generating some price objects and adding it to a std::vector, why the value of **close** inside the object Price for the first element is aparently a random value in memory ? is this a reference issue ?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Price{
public:
    double entry;
    double close;  
    Price(double initial){
        entry = initial;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Price> prices;
    bool open = false;
    int index = 1;
    std::cout << "#######  before  ########" << std::endl;
    while (index < 10){
        if (open){
            Price current = prices[prices.size() - 1];
            current.close = -current.entry;
            open = false;
            std::cout << "open: " << current.entry << " | close: " << current.close<<std::endl;
        }
        else{
            Price new_price(index);
            prices.push_back(new_price);
            open = true; 
        }
        ++index;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "#######  after  ########" << std::endl;
    for(const auto price: prices){
        std::cout << "open: " << price.entry << " | close: " << price.close << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output generated by the above code is:

```
#######  before  ########
open: 1 | close: -1
open: 3 | close: -3
open: 5 | close: -5
open: 7 | close: -7

#######  after  ########
open: 1 | close: 4.6799e-310
open: 3 | close: -1
open: 5 | close: -3
open: 7 | close: -5
open: 9 | close: -7
```

Also if i change `Price current = prices[prices.size() - 1];`to `Price& current = prices[prices.size() - 1];` the value of **close** for the last element is now corrupted and the first is fine. I am lost, can someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Did you mean for `index` to start from 0 instead of 1?

Comment: This code is unnecessarily complicated. I'd recommend using a for loop for `index` in`[0,4]`, remove `open` and group the two statements in one loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `#######  before  ########` list, you are printing objects with both of members `entry` and `close` are initialized.

On the other hand, objects with only `entry` is initialized is pushed to the vector `prices` and they are printed in the `#######  after  ########` list. (`Price current = prices[prices.size() - 1];` makes a copy of the object in the vector, so modification to `current` won't affect the elements in the vector. Uninitialized `double` members have indeterminate values, so your result is obtained by chance.

`Price& current = prices[prices.size() - 1];` will make modifications to `current` affect the elements of the vector, but the loop is executed only 9 times (`index = 1, 2, ... , 9`), so initialization of `close` is not done. You may want to change `while (index < 10)` to `while (index <= 10)` to eliminate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a reference issue.

```
Price current = prices[prices.size() - 1];
current.close = -current.entry;
```

This modifies the `close` member of a local variable `current`. This is not the same `Price` object as the one inside the vector `prices`; it's been copied.

Therefore, you actually *never* set `close` for `Price`s inside the vector! The "almost correct" values you see are just as unspecified as the really small one in the first element.

Instead:

```
Price& current = prices[prices.size() - 1];
current.close = -current.entry;
```

You don't see the problem in the first set of output, because you are printing that local variable's values, not the one in the vector.